# In a Visual Studio 2022 C# Solution, is it possible to have a local project which is not included in the repository?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, gitignore, solution

I am working on a C# solution which contains multiple projects.

I have one project I am just using as a scratch pad to test things out.

I don't want to include this in the repository as it is not for production or automated testing.

I tried to just simply add the project to .gitignore, but this causes the build to fail because the solution (.sln) file contains some references to it, like:

```
    
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Personio.Client.Demo", "Personio.Client.Demo\Personio.Client.Demo.csproj", "{994C7113-E779-4400-9213-3373D94D8528}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        {994C7113-E779-4400-9213-3373D94D8528}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {994C7113-E779-4400-9213-3373D94D8528}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {994C7113-E779-4400-9213-3373D94D8528}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {994C7113-E779-4400-9213-3373D94D8528}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
```

Is there any way I can tell the solution, just ignore it if (some) of these things are missing?  Or can I have a working project included in the solution but not this file?

(Of course, I can just put this project in a completely different solution, but that's obviously less convenient.)

Comment: I would not add the project to the solution, I'd create a separate solution and add projects to the solution as needed (i.e. "add existing project")

Comment: *I have one project I am just using as a scratch pad to test things out.* - i tend to use the interactive window, the immediate window, or something surrounded in `#if DEBUG`, or c# fiddle (if I don't need anything else from a project) for that.. Perhaps if it must be a lot more involved I'd also second Camilo's suggestion - you should have another solution (that you build for release) that doesn't have the scratch project in that sln, and develop with the one that does. Noone ever said you can have only one solution in a folder

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, As mentioned in the original message, the idea of a separate project has occurred to me and and I have done it.  however, it would be more convenient to keep the project in the solution since I can then navigate it, search it, refactor it, etc. concurrently without switching between windows.  And of course, I could just add it on demand, but then I also need to worry about removing it again.

Comment: @CaiusJard, I'll need to look into the interactive and immediate windows to see how they could help me out.   Can I use `#if DEBUG` in the .sln file?  Is it safe to assume that no part of the pipeline would evaluate this to true?

Comment: Er, no i wasn't intending for you to use #if DEBUG in a sln; it was e.g. so you could have a class full of junk code that *is* included in the proj/sln but would never accidentally be put into the prod codebase (if the entire class is #if DEBUG'd out)

Comment: I think you might have missed the significance of what camilo and I mentioned: a solution and a project are very different things. You can have a solution that has 3 projects: `DbAccess.csproj`, `TheUI.csproj` and `ScrappyTestCodes.csproj` and that is what you develop with.. and you can have ANOTHER soltuon that is just `DbAccess.csproj` and `TheUI.csproj` - that is what your production deploy pipeline builds and uses. Because ScrappyTestProject depends on the other two, but neither of them depend on ScrappyTest, then you can deploy to prod without ScrappyTest, or you can dev with it and..

Comment: ..write your junk codes (that use the DB, whatever) in there until it's time for them to graduate to somewhere in DB or UI. Because both SLN reference the same projects (and hence same files) on disk any changes you make while devving in SlnWithScrappyT.sln will be reflected in the prod build... the only thing you have to remember is when you add a whole new project to SlnWithScrappyT that *should* be deployed (i.e your dev env now has 4 projects), you need to add that project to SlnForProdWithoutScrappyT.sln too (otherwise the prod solution will have 2 projects, not 3)

Comment: Exactly what @CaiusJard said :) 2 solutions referencing the same projects - one gets pushed to source control, the other doesn't.